# Catch custom Exception in Silex isn't working as expected

Tags: php, error-handling, silex

I'm making an application in Silex.

Somewhere in my code I do `throw new OrderNotFoundException($message, 404);`

So the `$app->error` in my `index.php` will catch this.
I've implemented this as followed:

```
$app->error( function ( \Exception $e, $code ) use ( $app ) {
    $messages = [ ];

    switch ($code) {
        case 401:
            $messages[ 'message' ] = 'unauthorized';
            break;
        case 404:
            if($e instanceof OrderNotFoundException){
                $messages[ 'message' ] = 'no_order_found';
            } else {
                $messages[ 'message' ] = 'page_not_found';
            }
            break;
        case 409:
            if($e instanceof MultipleOrderException){
                $messages[ 'message' ] = 'multiple_orders';
            }
            break;
        default:
            $messages[ 'message' ] = 'unknown_error';
    }

    return $app[ 'twig' ]->render( 'home.twig', $messages );
} );
```

But I keep getting the `'unknown_error'`.
Is the `$code` that I throw with my exception passed correctly or should I do this another way?

Making an new Error-function for every Exceptions seems not the good way I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrderNotFoundException` should implement `HttpExceptionInterface`. In this case you can extend `NotFoundHttpException`:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\NotFoundHttpException;

class OrderNotFoundException extends NotFoundHttpException {}
```

and just throw the exception with

```
throw new OrderNotFoundException($message);
```

Comment: And what about my `MultipleOrderException`? I now throw it like `throw new OrderNotFoundException($message, 409);` so I think I should do `class MultipleOrderExceptionextends ConflictHttpException{}` than?

Comment: `OrderNotFoundException` imply that the exception is only for 404 code. (Not Found). If you want use other http status, then call it `OrderException` and extend the generic [HttpException](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/master/Exception/HttpException.php) class, or add new specific exception class for those http status

Comment: OK that's more clear now thanks :-) I'll take yours and @DarkBee's answer in consideration :-)

Answer (score 1):

Imho you would be better of doing it this like :

```
$app->error( function (OrderNotFoundException $e, $code ) use ( $app ) {

});


$app->error( function (MultipleOrderException $e, $code ) use ( $app ) {

});

//...

$app->error( function (Exception $e, $code ) use ( $app ) {


});
```

Comment: That's just what I don't think is a good idea. 'cause then you have almost the same in every error-function
`$messages[ 'message' ] = 'no_order_found'; return $app[ 'twig' ]->render( 'home.twig', $messages );`

Comment: `function createMessage($type) use($app) {
    return $app->render('template.twig', [ 'type' => $type,]);
}` to prevent duplicate code

Comment: That's not helping, 'cause then I allways need to say `$type = 'no_order_found'; createMessage($type);` in every Error-function. It's the same amount of _duplication_ and that's what I don't have know in my Switch Case

Comment: It sure is more readable, what if you register 2 more exceptions, in which for example you will need to send an e-mail or log activity to database? It is just a flavor. I know.. Do note `$code` has to be an HTTP status code. In your case your are making everything into a `200` request.